# How to display the child array in angular ag grid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

here's the code:

```
rowData = [{
 room: 'Room 1',
 data: [{ 
  name: 'justin'
 },{
  name: 'josh'
 }];
},{
 room: 'Room 2',
 data: [{ 
  name: 'juan'
 },{
  name: 'luna'
 }];
}];

columnDefs = [{
      headerName: 'Room',
      field: 'room'
},{
      headerName: 'Name',
      field: 'name'
}]
```

***HTML***

```
 <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

What I'm trying to do is to display the child array in the grid.
but when I try to run/console it return undefined.

also I tried this:

```
  valueGetter: function(params: any) {
    return console.log(params.data.data.name);
  }
```

it return undefined

Answer (score 1):

`params.data.data[0].name` is the correct expression

Because the data attribute in row is actually array of names. You can also put a check like

`if(params.data.data && params.data.data.length > 0){
return params.data.data[0].name;
} else{
return '' ;
}`

Answer (score 1):

1. Define name field in colDef like `'data.name'`
   `valueGetter: this.customValueGetter`
2. I would use `customValueGetter` like -

```
 customValueGetter(params) {
```

const items;    
  const columnField = params.colDef.field;  
  const arrayNm = columnField.split(".")[0];  
  const fieldNm = columnField.split(".")[1];  

  if(params.data && params.data[arrayNm]) {  
   params.data[arrayNm].forEach((item) => items.push(item[fieldNm]));  
  }  
   return items.join(","); //comma separated names  
}